# Weird RDP glitch

Tags: remote-desktop

I suddenly have a weird glitch in my RDP sessions. On every white area, that has no content, this stuff is painted. I have no clue how it started. Restarting all my devices (source & target) did nothing, the glitch is still there. My best guess is that the Remote Desktop client uses a buffer to quickly paint empty areas white and that this buffer got somehow poisoned. Any ideas on how to get rid of this?
[image: Poisoned RDP Buffer]

**Versions**:

Both Machines run on Win10 20H2 19042.928, using the RDP Server & Client included in the Windows Installation which are both on Version 10.0.19041 (both Shell and Control) and support RDP Protocol Version 10.8

Comment: Which operating systems (with version) for the RDP client and server?

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is weird. This error persisted through multiple restarts and multiple days, then vanished as quickly as it came. Without a restart. The only thing I did was having a Zoom-Meeting. So I guess Zoom did indeed somehow poison the buffer but fixed it itself? I have no clue what just happened. But if anyone has a similar problem this might help.